Determining the Center of Rotation in a Video: A Mathematical Approach
I have a video where the camera rotates, causing the images to rotate around a specific point. I need to determine the coordinates of this rotation center.
Here's my plan: I use a function to measure the angle of rotation between two images. With this information, I can re-align subsequent images to match the orientation of the first one (rotate it around the center of the frame). Then, I calculate the lateral translation (dx, dy) between them using correlation. The challenge lies in pinpointing the exact coordinates of the rotation center using the angle and the (dx, dy) data.
I think about this in this way: Assume I have an origin point O (the center of the frame) and a center of rotation C. An arbitrary point A (a1,a2) on the image is rotated around C (c1,c2), resulting in point B (b1,b2). Then, I rotate point B around O, transforming it into point D (d1,d2).
Before calculations, pay attention: I don't really have any coordinate A on the image. I Assume this point (and its transformations B and D) only for calculations, and finally I need to eliminate any dependence on the variables a1,a1,b1,b2,d1 and d2.
I can use the matrix of rotation around an Point C (watch here).
(1) b1=a1 cos⁡θ-a2 sin⁡θ+c1 cos⁡θ-c2 sin⁡θ-c1
(2) b2=a1 sin⁡θ+a2 cos⁡θ+c1 sin⁡θ+c2 cos⁡θ-c2

Since AC=AB (these are both radii):
(3) (a1-c1)^2+(a2-c2)^2=(b1-c1)^2+(b2-b2)^2

From the rotation of B aroun O in the opposite direction:
(4) d1=b1 cos⁡(-θ)-b2 sin(-⁡θ)
(5) d2=b1 sin⁡(-θ)+b2 cos(-⁡θ)

And since OB=OD:
(6) b1^2+b2^2=d1^2+d2^2

I also can get 2 equations from the Cosine law (triangles ACB and BOD):
(7) (a1-b1)^2+(a2-b2)^2=√([(b1-c1)^2+(b2-b2)^2])*√(2-2 cos⁡θ)

(8) (b1-d1)^2+(b2-d2)^2=√([b1^2+b2^2])*√(2-2 cos⁡θ)

As I understand, the aim is to get two expressions:
dx = a1-d1 = f1(c1,c2,θ)

dy = a2-d2 = f2(c1,c2,θ)

and from these two expressions I can get (c1,c2).
My problem is that I can't solve these equation to get functions of the variables c1,c2,θ only.
Is there anyone out there persistent enough to crack this puzzle? Or perhaps a different angle of attack? :-)
